# How to keychain shortcuts in xfce. For example to switch the workspace

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

In xfce I would like to switch to a particular workplace by pressing two keys after each other. for example first <kbd>F2</kbd> and than the letter <kbd>A</kbd>. <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> together is hard to type for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program, switches to screen 0-9 and a-z, (11 - 37). It needs to callable `chmod +x switcher.py` and be called by a shortcut in key/shortcuts.

```
import subprocess


import Tkinter as tk


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry('200x200+0+0')
        master.bind('<KeyPress>', self.react_to_keypress)
        master.after(2500, quit)

    def react_to_keypress(self, event):
        key = event.char.lower()
        try:
            int(key)
        except ValueError:
            if ord(key) < 97 or ord(key) > 122:
                return False
            else:
                key = str(ord(key) - 97 + 10)
                print key
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/wmctrl", "-s " + key])

    def quit(self):
        self.master.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```